# How to change default program to open magnet link in windows?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, windows-8.1, utorrent, magnet-links

Recently I installed BitComet. Now when I click a torrent magnet link from chrome it opens with BitComet though I changed the settings of BitComet to not to be the default program to open magnet links. I couldn't find default magnet link settings in μTorrent. I want my default program to open magnet links to be μTorrent.
I'm using Windows 8.1 and my browser is Chrome, I want to make the default program to open magnet links to be μTorrent.

Comment: I had to deselect the 'open magnet link' option in qTorrent - then Apply, then reselect it - and it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Open μTorrent. Go to preferences from options menu. Select general. Click the button **Associate with torrent files**. Your problem is over.

Comment: Wrong answer gets 29 upvotes. He said Magnet, not torrent.

Comment: Worked for me in Transmission Remote GUI, there is option for files and magnets.

Answer (score 29):

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type `regedit` and press OK.
2. Browse to the following location:

   ```
   HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Magnet\shell\open\command
   ```
3. Double-click the default location and change the data section to:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\uTorrent\uTorrent.exe" "%L"
   ```

Comment: This answer also works for Transmission and in fact any other program given the right path, thanks!

Comment: after last windows update this doesnt work anymore (it worked for changing from utorrent to qBittorrent), but now no magnetic links open

Comment: Shouldn't that "%L" be a "%1"?

Comment: This answer works, thanks. I use WebTorrent, so the path for me was `"C:\Users\MyUsername\AppData\Local\WebTorrent\app-0.24.0\WebTorrent.exe" "%1"`

Answer (score 17):

You need to change the "Handlers" setting inside the Chrome Settings.

Click the Chrome menu on the browser toolbar.

Select Settings > Show advanced settings.

In the "Privacy" section, click Content settings.

In the dialog that appears, find the “Handlers” section. Click Manage handlers.

Use the drop-down menu next to a listed protocol to select the web service that should be used by default.

P.S - This answer was for a pretty old version of Chrome. The settings have changed since then and I don't use Chrome anymore, so maybe try some of the other answers.

Comment: ?? This doesn't work the list is read-only? See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkkOU.png

Comment: The settings layout has recently changed to make everything even more difficult than it already was. There is no "Manage handlers" any more.

Comment: In macOS Catalina, using Chrome v86 and Transmission, the "Handlers" route did not work for me. However, opening Transmission, going into Preferences and then clicking the "Accept magnet links: [Set Default Application]" button worked! Chrome now offers to open magnet links in Transmission. yay!

Comment: MS Edge: Settings > Cookies and site permissions > Protocol handlers

Answer (score 4):

Late answer, but this may help people specifically trying to use Deluge in Windows. Which I think they stopped updating in 2017.

Windows wants you to choose a magnet handler through a specific options screen, "Choose a default app for each protocol". But that screen doesn't have 'magnet'.

The problem is that windows is missing some registry stuff for magnet links. In most torrent programs, you can check some option to make your program the preferred magnet handler. Checking that option adds the needed registry info. But Deluge doesn't have any such option.

**The fix**

The earlier answer with a registry fix is mostly correct. Where you might get frustrated is if you try to just add that key manually like this:

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Magnet\shell\open\command
```

then, change default value to...

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Deluge\deluge.exe" "%1"
```

This will result in nothing happening when you click magnet links. The reason it doesn't work, is because there's a few other details that need to go into the magnet subkey in the registry. There's two ways to add those details. The easy way is to just install a modern torrent client like qbittorrent. The necessary registry stuffs will be created. then you can change the registry path so that it points to Deluge insead of QBittorent.

The other way is to manually add the missing items. Out of laziness I'll just screenshot these:

[image: magnet registry entries]

you can see there's also a "Default icon" key, I'm not sure if this is needed. Mine has one value, the default, which is set to: "C:\Program Files\qBittorrent\qbittorrent.exe",1

Hope this helps if anyone can't get magnet links to behave.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are talking about windows

Chrome uses the windows default handler for the filetypes. Just search for "Default Apps" in your start menu and change the association there, and chrome will then call the correct file.

[image: Settings]

I just did this on win10 for .torrent

Comment: This helped me to find the Default app per Protocol which was what I needed.

Comment: The question asks for magnets, this answer relates to .torrent files.

Comment: Like the comment above yours, it helps resolve the issue, somehow *shrugs*

Answer (score 0):

HOW TO FIX  Chrome version 63 or higher keeps popping  up mod window of "always open these types of links in the associated app" even after clicking - it doesn't remember - bugs chrome -.. 
1) Go to search box on your taskbar and type "run"
2) In Run, type %appdata% and press OK.
3) Press AppData on the top, and go to 
Navigate  to C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Preferences
4) Open it with Notepad.
5) Press Ctrl+ F and find "protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{}}, and click Find Next.
6) Replace that part with "protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"magnet":false}},?

for torrent magnet links

or for roblox users instead Replace that part with

"protocol_handler":{"excluded_schemes":{"ROBLOX":false}}"?

Comment: For me this answer was (part of) the solution. Chrome did not handle the new torrent client and kept using the old one. I uninstalled the old one, added the excluded_schemes from this answer and re-checked magnet association in the new torrent client. After a reboot everything is working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

For qBittorrent users on Windows 11.
This script will add qBittorrent as a handler for the magnet protocol on the registry using the correct paths:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.magnet]
@="URL:magnet"
"Content Type"="application/x-magnet"
"URL Protocol"=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.magnet\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qBittorrent\\qbittorrent.exe\",0"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.magnet\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.magnet\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.magnet\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qBittorrent\\qbittorrent.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.torrent]
"Content Type"="application/x-bittorrent"
@="Torrent file"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.torrent\DefaultIcon]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qBittorrent\\qbittorrent.exe\",1"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.torrent\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.torrent\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\qBittorrent.torrent\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qBittorrent\\qbittorrent.exe\" \"%1\""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\RegisteredApplications]
"qBittorrent"="Software\\qBittorrent\\Capabilities"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent\Capabilities]
"ApplicationIcon"="C:\\Program Files\\qBittorrent\\qbittorrent.exe,1"
"ApplicationName"="qBittorrent"
"ApplicationDescription"="Torrent downloader"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent\Capabilities\URLAssociations]
"magnet"="qBittorrent.magnet"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent\Capabilities\FileAssociations]
".torrent"="qBittorrent.torrent"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent\shell]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\qBittorrent\shell\open\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\qBittorrent\\qbittorrent.exe\""
```

Afterwards you will need to open Windows Settings > Apps > Default apps.
Search for magnet and qBittorrent will show up.

[image: protocol handler]

All of this is needed because the developers refuse update their implementation, sticking to the way file associations used to work on Windows XP.
Reference: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/2517